# How many ways to assign grades to keep an average?

Tags: combinatorics

$100$ students can get grades that are divisible by 5 from $0$ to $100$. How many ways are there to assign their grades such that the average is at least 60? The solution should use inclusion-exclusion and can be left with sums.

I'm unsure of how to start with this one. Not even sure what to include-exclude. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In order for their average to be at least $60$, their *sum* must be at least $60\cdot 5 = 300$.  This is just a stars-and-bars problem.  The inclusion-exclusion comes into play when considering whether any violate the condition that scores cannot exceed 100 for a particular result.

Comment: @JMoravitz: You meant $60\cdot100 =6000$

Comment: I sure did... How did that happen?  I guess I saw the 5 in "divisible by 5" and my mind filled in the blanks... thinking it was just one student and five assignments.  The reference to stars-and-bars and inclusion-exclusion are still relevant though and the suggested approach is still the same.

Comment: Off-topic: The teacher should set the lowest mark in a humane manner and allow student marks slide such as the highest mark is 100 regardless the absolute level attained, while the resulting average is whatever. The reason for such a marking protocol is that both the student and the teacher contribute to final mark thus discard the marking down from the best mark obtained as representing teacher’s  fault. Then compute teacher’s performance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preparations**: First, we formalize the problem. Let $\mathcal G=\{g\in 5\mathbb Z:0\le g\le 100\}$ be the grades. Then we want to know the size $|\mathcal S|$ of $$\mathcal S=\left\{g\in\mathcal G^{100}:\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}g_i\ge 60\right\}=\left\{g\in\mathcal G^{100}:\sum_{i=1}^{100}g_i\ge 6000\right\}.$$
Now, let $\mathcal G_\circ=\{0,\dots,20\}$ and
$\mathcal S_\circ=\{g\in\mathcal G_\circ^{100}:\sum_{i=1}^{100}g_i\ge 1200\}$. Then we have $\mathcal G=5\mathcal G_\circ$ and
$$\mathcal S=\left\{5g:g\in\mathcal G_\circ^{100},5\sum_{i=1}^{100}g_i\ge 6000\right\}=5\mathcal S_\circ.$$
So, we have $|\mathcal S|=|\mathcal S_\circ|$ and don't have to deal with multiples of five and averages anymore.

Next, we split the set $\mathcal S_\circ=\bigcup_{t=1200}^{2000}\mathcal S_{t}$ into sets $\mathcal S_t=\{g\in\mathcal G_\circ^{100}:\sum_{i=1}^{100}g_i=t\}$ with fixed totals. This gives $|\mathcal S_\circ|=\sum_{t=1200}^{2000}|\mathcal S_t|$, and now it is sufficient to understand $\mathcal X=\mathcal S_t$ for fixed $1200\le t\le 2000$.

**Counting**: We follow the approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4616114/1096797) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1006830/1096797). So, let $\mathcal T_s=\{x\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}^{100}:\sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i=t\}$ and let $\mathcal T_{s,i,u}=\{x\in\mathcal T_{s}:x_i\ge u\}$, which we only need for $\mathcal A_i=\mathcal T_{t,i,21}$ here. Then we have
$\mathcal X=\mathcal T_{t}\setminus\bigcup_i\mathcal A_i$, so we can use the Inclusion-Exclusion-Principle to obtain
$$|\mathcal X|=|\mathcal T_t|-\sum_{k=1}^{100}(-1)^{k+1}\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_k\le 100}\left|\bigcap_{j=1}^k\mathcal A_{i_j}\right|.$$
First, notice that $|\mathcal T_s|=\binom{s+100-1}{s}=\binom{s+99}{s}$ using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). Further, notice that
$$\mathcal T_{s,i,u}
=\left\{x\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}^{100}:\sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i=s,x_i\ge u\right\}
=\left\{x+u\mathrm e_i:x\in\mathcal T_{s-u}\right\},$$
where $\mathrm e_i\in\{0,1\}^{100}$ denotes the $i$-th unit vector.
Similarly, we have
$$\bigcap_{j=1}^k\mathcal T_{s,i_j,u_j}
=\left\{x\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}^{100}:\sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i=s,(x_{i_j})_j\ge (u_{j})_j\right\}
=\left\{x+\sum_{j=1}^ku_j\mathrm e_{i_j}:x\in\mathcal T_{s-\sum_ju_j}\right\},$$
and hence $|\bigcap_{j=1}^k\mathcal T_{s,i_j,u_j}|=|\mathcal T_{s-\sum_ju_j}|=\binom{s-\sum_ju_j+99}{s-\sum_ju_j}$.
With these results we obtain
\begin{align*}
|\mathcal X|&=\binom{t+99}{t}-\sum_{k=1}^{100}(-1)^{k+1}\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_k\le 100}\binom{t-21k+99}{t-21k}\\
&=\binom{t+99}{t}-\sum_{k=1}^{100}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{100}{k}\binom{t-21k+99}{t-21k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^{k}\binom{100}{k}\binom{t-21k+99}{t-21k}.
\end{align*}

**Alternative**: We can also follow the approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1049080/1096797).
The generating function for a single student is $f(x)=\sum_{g=0}^{20}x^g=\frac{1-x^{21}}{1-x}$ and the generating function for the sum is $S(x)=f(x)^{100}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{100}}\sum_{s=0}^{100}\binom{100}{s}(-1)^sx^{21s}$. We recall the generating function $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{100}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+100-1}{n}x^n$ for stars and bars from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Proofs_by_generating_functions), and hence obtain $S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{s=0}^{100}\binom{n+100-1}{n}\binom{100}{s}(-1)^sx^{n+21s}$. Extracting the coefficient for $x^t$ yields $\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\binom{t-21k+99}{t-21k}\binom{100}{k}$.